# Return 10% of records for each group that meet a certain criteria

Tags: sql

I am trying to query a table that has multiple groups to get 10% of the systems in each group that meet a certain criteria.

Here's the data:

```
create table tablename as
select '4FH6V1' as ComputerName, 'AZ1' as Location, '3093' as Rating from dual union all
select '0GLYQ1' as ComputerName, 'AZ1' as Location, '3093' as Rating from dual union all
select 'P191R1' as ComputerName, 'AZ1' as Location, '3093' as Rating from dual union all
select '7CMJ02' as ComputerName, 'AZ3' as Location, '3392' as Rating from dual union all
select '8W2QS1' as ComputerName, 'AZ4' as Location, '3093' as Rating from dual union all
select 'K9CHX1' as ComputerName, 'AZ7' as Location, '3192' as Rating from dual union all
select '3XZNS1' as ComputerName, 'AZ7' as Location, '3093' as Rating from dual union all
select '79RGX1' as ComputerName, 'AZ9' as Location, '3192' as Rating from dual union all
select '02BR22' as ComputerName, 'AZ3' as Location, '2593' as Rating from dual
;

| ComputerName | Location | Rating |
|--------------|----------|--------|
| 4FH6V1       | AZ1      | 3093   |
| 0GLYQ1       | AZ1      | 3093   |
| P191R1       | AZ1      | 3093   |
| 7CMJ02       | AZ3      | 3392   |
| 8W2QS1       | AZ4      | 3093   |
| K9CHX1       | AZ7      | 3192   |
| 3XZNS1       | AZ7      | 3093   |
| 79RGX1       | AZ9      | 3192   |
| 02BR22       | AZ3      | 2593   |
```

There are many more records like this in the table. For example, I need to find 10% of the Computer Names in each Location that have the Rating of 3093.

Comment: How do you expect people to help if you don't even give enough info?  What SQL are you using?  The syntax are different between different dbms.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL server you can use the `PERCENT` in your `select` statement:

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * FROM tablename WHERE RATING=3093;
```

Comment: I think that will just return 10% of all the locations combined and not 10% for each location separately.  So I need the Computer names broken out by location and only 10% of that have the Rating of 3093.  I was using PERCENT, but can't figure out the rest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This should work on Oracle, although the sample data is not large enough to get a 10% sample...

```
create table tablename as
select '4FH6V1' as ComputerName, 'AZ1' as Location, '3093' as Rating from dual union all
select '0GLYQ1' as ComputerName, 'AZ1' as Location, '3093' as Rating from dual union all
select 'P191R1' as ComputerName, 'AZ1' as Location, '3093' as Rating from dual union all
select '7CMJ02' as ComputerName, 'AZ3' as Location, '3392' as Rating from dual union all
select '8W2QS1' as ComputerName, 'AZ4' as Location, '3093' as Rating from dual union all
select 'K9CHX1' as ComputerName, 'AZ7' as Location, '3192' as Rating from dual union all
select '3XZNS1' as ComputerName, 'AZ7' as Location, '3093' as Rating from dual union all
select '79RGX1' as ComputerName, 'AZ9' as Location, '3192' as Rating from dual union all
select '02BR22' as ComputerName, 'AZ3' as Location, '2593' as Rating from dual
;

with cte1 as (
select
   x.ComputerName
  ,x.Location
  ,x.Rating
  ,count(1) over (partition by Location) as location_total
  ,row_number() over (partition by Location order by ComputerName) as location_position
  ,row_number() over (partition by Location order by ComputerName) / count(1) over (partition by Location) as location_pct
from tablename x
where x.Rating = 3093
)
select *
from cte1
where location_pct <= 0.1
```

Comment: Nice one.  FYI: Remove `from dual` and it would also work on MSSQL (or create a dummy table with 1 row called dual).  `create table dual (x bit); insert dual select 1`.

Comment: This is great. I need to modify it because it's not getting the exact result for some reason. I have 184 computers that meet the x.Rating = 3093 criteria when I count manually, but the query only is returning 9, when it should be 18. I am a noob, so I don't fully understand the over / partition statements fully.

Comment: If you can post a bigger sample of your data it would be easier to figure out where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

It you are using SQL Server, you can use `apply`:

```
select tt.*
from (select distinct location from t where t.rating = 3093) l apply
     (select top (10) PERCENT t.*
      from t
      where t.location = l.location and t.rating = 3093
     ) tt
```